# How do hybrid cars reduce carbon emissions (wouldn't they just transfer fuel emissions to electricity consumption?)

Tags: environmental-protection

How do hybrid cars reduce carbon emissions (wouldn't they just transfer fuel emissions to electricity consumption?)

Doing an accounting project on upgrading fuel supplied  cars to hybrids and we're spending a lot of money to set up charging stations. But i got to thinking wouldn't the fuel save just transfer into energy consumed?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is on-topic here or not. It's been covered elsewhere on the network, on [Sustainability.SE](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/1061/48) and [here](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/612/48) , on [skeptics.se](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/15008/6236), and a bit on [physics.se](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66851/4066)

Comment: (I agree it's at least boundary off-topic here.) 1st: You recuperate energy from breaking and downhills. 2nd: You don't spend fuel in traffic jams (this is the most important thing IMHO). 3rd: You can use atoms, Sahara sun one day maybe etc., whatever energy source to have electricity, but only oil to have combustion.

Comment: @tohecz and everyone - please join in [the related meta discussion](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/334/100)

Comment: @Ivan the main difference is that the new electrical energy consumed has less cost (and less emissions) because it comes from a power plant and not your car+gasoline.  I've seen estimates that powering cars entirely from electricity would result in about 80% less carbon emissions due to vehicles.  Though, that is for commuter vehicles only as far as I know.  The key to this is that burning gasoline in a car only captures about 8% of the chemical energy in the fuel, which is very inefficient.